# Adaptive learning rate with fixed schedule

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a convolutional neural net using an adaptive learning rate and Adam gradient-based optimization. I have the following code:

```
# learning rate schedule
schedule = np.array([0.0005, 0.0005,
       0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002,
       0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001,
       0.00005, 0.00005, 0.00005, 0.00005,
       0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001])

# define placeholder for variable learning rate
learning_rates = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None),name='learning_rate')

# training operation
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, 
labels=one_hot_y)
loss_operation = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rates)
training_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)
```

Code for running the session:

```
.
.
.
_, loss = sess.run([training_operation, loss_operation], 
               feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, learning_rate: schedule[i]})
.
.
.
```

The i represents the epoch count which is initialized at 0 so it should technically use the first value in the schedule.

Whenever I try to run this I get the following error:

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'learning_rate_2' with dtype float
     [[Node: learning_rate_2 = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Has anyone had the same issue? I tried reinitializing the session, renaming variables but to no avail.

Comment: try this, define schedule inside the session

Comment: Hi Ali, that didn't work either but I found another around. I removed the learning_rates placeholder and copied the optimizer variable into my training loop. Not very elegant but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an intermediate solution.

```
.
.
.
for i in range(EPOCHS):
    XX_train, yy_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)

    # code for adaptive rate
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = schedule[i])

    for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
        end = offset + BATCH_SIZE
        batch_x, batch_y = XX_train[offset:end], yy_train[offset:end]
        _, loss = sess.run([training_operation, loss_operation], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
.
.
.
```

Not very elegant but at least it works.